# Whole form submited even with Ajax Listener

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am new in JSF development. I am using Eclipse with JDK 1.8.0_172, WildFly 16, JSF 2.3, PrimeFaces 7.0 datatable. I have developed a page called FrmTest.xhtml with a managed bean with view scope. After page is loaded, when user clicks on NEW button,  I want to add a new row to the datatable. But the whole form is submitted . I understood that ajax does the processing without submitting the whole form. What should I change so that the whole form is not submitted but the row is added to the datatable ?

The xhtml is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>    
    </h:head>
    <h:body>


        <div class="ToolBar" style="background-color:cadetblue;padding:10px;" > 
            <h:commandButton id="btnNewP"   value="new" global="false">
                <f:ajax event="click" execute="btnNewP" listener="#{testing.ButtonNew}" render="dataList"  />
            </h:commandButton>  
        </div>  

        <h:form id="FrmTest">  

            <p:dataTable id="dataList" value="#{testing.getListDto()}"  var="lst" Form="FrmTest" paginator="true" rows="20" paginatorPosition="top"  editable="true" editMode="cell"  rowKey="#{lst.vsCode}" rowIndexVar="rowNumber" selectionMode="single">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        List of Vat Status
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:column  headerText="Selected">
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{lst.isSelected}"  />
                        </div>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="Code" headerText="Code">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{lst.vsCode}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText value="#{lst.vsCode}" >
                                <p:ajax event = "blur" listener="#{testing.onCellBlur(rowNumber, 'Code')}" update="dataList"  />
                                </p:inputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>                 

                    <p:column id="Name" headerText="Name">
                         <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{lst.vsName}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText value="#{lst.vsName}" >
                                <p:ajax event = "blur" listener="#{testing.onCellBlur(rowNumber, 'Name')}" update="dataList"  /> 
                                </p:inputText>
                            </f:facet>
                         </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="Description" headerText="Description">
                         <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{lst.vsDescription}"  />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText value="#{lst.vsDescription}" >
                                <p:ajax event = "blur" listener="#{testing.onCellBlur(rowNumber, 'Description')}" update="dataList"  /> 
                                </p:inputText>
                            </f:facet>
                         </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column  headerText="is Active">
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{lst.isActive}"  />
                        </div>
                    </p:column>                     

                    <p:column headerText="Modified By" style="display:none;">
                        <h:outputText id="ModifiedBy" value="#{lst.modifiedBy}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Modified Date" style="display:none;">
                        <h:outputText id="ModifiedDate" value="#{lst.modifiedDate}" />
                    </p:column>     

                    <p:column headerText="Row State" style="display:none;">
                        <h:outputText id="RowState" value="#{lst.rowState}" />
                    </p:column>     

                    <p:column headerText="Error Description" style="display:none;">
                        <h:outputText id="ErrorDescription" value="#{lst.errorDescription}" />
                    </p:column>     

            </p:dataTable>

          </h:form> 

    </h:body>

</html>
```

The coding for the NEW button is as follows

```
public void ButtonNew() {

try {
    System.out.println("ButtonNew, Entry");

    Date modifiedDate = new Date(); 
    dtoUpdated = new VatStatusDto(false, " ", " ", " ", 0.00, " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "Y", true,  getSessionUserCode(), modifiedDate, modifiedDate.toString(),  " ", " ", "Added");    

    listDto.add(0, dtoUpdated);
    PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("FrmTest:dataList");

}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("FrmTest, ButtonNew: " + e.getMessage() + ", " + e.getCause() + ", " + e.getStackTrace());       
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

> I understood that ajax does the processing without submitting the whole form.

No, then you understood wrong (at least in the context of basic ajax and PrimeFaces/JSF). This is not what ajax does... Ajax basically 'only' does a partial page update, updating in the **response** only those parts of the page that are told to be updated. There is nothing in 'ajax' that states it should optimze other things like (by default) do a partial process/execute of form elements server side or force the client to  partially submit the form (inputs) from the client to the server.

The behaviour of the [PrimeFaces update/process or plain JSF render/execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes) attributes has a good section on optimizing which parts are actually submitted from the client. You can effectively do this per input, form or globally (complete application), hence I won't duplicate that part here.

See also:

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/ajax/partialsubmit?id=partial-submit
- https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/partialSubmit.xhtml

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the partial update, but the problem remain. I do not want the whole page being submitted when adding a new line. How to achieve that ?

Comment: Start reading the links **carefully**... (partial) update != partial submit...

Answer (score 0):

@Kukeltje, thanks a lot for your input. I read what you sent. I removed all the PrimeFaces objects, all the ajax calls. The problem remained. The problem was due to a stupid error from me. My managed bean, view scoped, extended another class marked as Request Scoped. I changed it to view scoped, when I click the command button, the whole form submit does not occur anymore.

Comment: I guess your own definition of "whole form submitted" is different from what we expected. You might want to instead describe in technical terms what exactly "whole form submitted" means to you. We of course understood that it means that the HTTP payload contains **all** form elements instead of only the ones defined in `process` attribute of the PrimeFaces Ajax component. This has namely got nothing to do with bean scopes.